# No puedo crear una nueva carpeta en una nueva ventana de Tkinter

Tags: python-3.x

Al momento de darle clic al botón para que me abra la nueva ventana y intentar darle clic al botón de la nueva ventana, no me crear la nueva carpeta con el texto que puse en la caja de texto. Ya intente import el def escaneo():, ya intente poner grid, pero no me funciona, aquí dejo el código:

```
from tkinter import * 
from tkinter.ttk import *
import os

principal = Tk()
principal.title("Escuela")
principal.geometry("200x200") 

def openNewWindow():
  newWindow = Toplevel(principal)
  newWindow.title("Preparación de escaneo")
  newWindow.geometry("200x200")
  Label(newWindow, text ="Marque el boton para preparar el escaneo").pack()
  boton = Button(newWindow, text = "Escaneo", command = lambda: os.makedirs(entry(newWindow).get()))
  boton.pack(pady = 10)
  entry = Entry(newWindow).pack()
  entry.place(x=50, y=50)
  mainloop()

label = Label(principal, text ="Preparar escaneo")
label.pack(pady = 10)

botones = Button(principal, text ="Para Escaneo", command = openNewWindow)
botones.pack(pady = 10)

mainloop()
```

Aquí dejo lo que me sale a recopilar:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buen día,

Hay unos errores de concepto en tu código

1. Los métodos `grid`, `pack` y `place` devuevlen `None` por lo que la línea

```
entry = Entry(newWindow).pack()
```

Está mal, eso hace que la variable `entry` sea `None`

Debe ser así:

```
entry = Entry(newWindow)
entry.pack()
```

2. La variable `entry` no es una función, por lo tanto no puedes pasarle parámetros, por lo que la línea

```
boton = Button(newWindow, text = "Escaneo", command = lambda: os.makedirs(entry(newWindow).get()))
```

Está mal, estás intentando pasar un argumento `newWindow` a la variable `entry` que no es una función

Debería ser así:

```
boton = Button(newWindow, text = "Escaneo", command = lambda: os.makedirs(entry.get()))
```

Arreglando esos dos problemas ya funciona.

**Nota:** Modifiqué la posición del `entry` porque se encimaba con el botón.

Ejemplo completo:

```
from tkinter import * 
from tkinter.ttk import *
import os

principal = Tk()
principal.title("Escuela")
principal.geometry("200x200") 

def openNewWindow():
    newWindow = Toplevel(principal)
    newWindow.title("Preparación de escaneo")
    newWindow.geometry("200x200")
    Label(newWindow, text ="Marque el boton para preparar el escaneo").pack()
    boton = Button(newWindow, text = "Escaneo", command = lambda: os.makedirs(entry.get()))
    boton.pack(pady = 10)
    entry = Entry(newWindow)
    entry.pack()
    entry.place(x=50, y=60)
    

label = Label(principal, text ="Preparar escaneo")
label.pack(pady = 10)

botones = Button(principal, text ="Para Escaneo", command = openNewWindow)
botones.pack(pady = 10)

mainloop()
```

Comment: una pregunta cuando pones la nueva ventana tiene que poner si o si openNewWindow en def y ponerlo como variable newWindow, o puedes poner otra palabra. Por cierto gracias por ayudarme con el código.

Comment: No, es posible darles cualquier nombre... Recuerda que es importante investigar o intentar antes de preguntar